# Xcode - Logout button

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, view, subview

Apparently, I have one `LoginViewController` and a `StartUpController`.

- `LoginViewController` has functionality to authenticate user and register new user (`presentModalViewController`). Once the user has logged in, my system will display `StartUpController`.

Inside this `StartUpController`, I have everything such as TabBarController, NavigationController, etc. This `StartUpController` is actually handling 5 different views.

My question is: what should I do to remove all of my views when my user click on "LogOut" button from one of my view?

I want to show my LoginViewController again.. but at the same time, remove the StartUpController view and all its views.

Please teach me how to do this:

Answer (score 3):

If your authentication view is your root view controller's view, use the [`-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW4) method on your navigation controller reference, e.g.:

```
[myNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Assuming you're not doing any weirdness with view controller ownership, the navigation controller will release the children view controllers (which, in turn, should release their views and other properties).

Comment: Thank Alex.. I will have a look at "popToRootViewControllerAnimated:"

Comment: FYI - I'm using this line to clear all the VC's because depending on which flow, my app does or does not use navigation controllers.  This appears to clear all them that are on the nav stack.

[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];